# Subspace reduction for eigenpair calculations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, machine-learning

As it is well-known, eigenpair calculations for large systems can get very expensive. At least, after taking the type of application into consideration, is it feasible to find a "shape" for something like an abstract subspace in which the eigenvectors for a certain amount of smallest eigenvalues live in? Could this be done in way of finding a relevant mapping, metric, or parametrization?

I am thinking about using Graph Neural Networks to extract useful structural information of molecules and feed it into a sort of subspace regression algorithm for the purpose of speeding up Density Functional Theory calculations.

EDIT: Clarified that the problem doesn't involve finding all eigenpairs of a system, i.e., a certain amount corresponding to the smallest eigenvalues.

Comment: In general, the eigenvectors of an operator span the entire space (there are exceptions, but these are rare).

Comment: Is there a difference between saying that they span an entire space and the entire space? From my impression, there are eigensolvers for large sparse matrices which start with an initial space and iteratively refine the initial guess until arriving in a space that is close enough to the exact space containing the eigenvectors.

Comment: The point of DFT isn't to find all eigenvalues but to find some amount of smallest eigenvalues which is used to calculate the ground state.

Comment: The "span" of a set of vectors consists of all vectors that can written as a linear combination of vectors in the set. It is the smallest vector subspace that contains the set. The operators whose eigenvectors do not span all of $\Bbb R^n$ form a subset of $\Bbb R^{n^2}$ of dimension $\Bbb R^{n^2 - 1}$. I.e, practically every operator is not in that subset. The solvers you mention are solving for the eigenspace of a single eigenvalue, not all of them. However, since you have clarified that you are only interested in eigenvectors for a subset of the eigenvalues, this has become a moot point.

Comment: The context of my problem is a coupled or nonlinear eigenvalue problem which is solved with a self-consistent field scheme which is embedded with an eigensolving routine. This is a paper I've looked into in the past that is relevant https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PDF/umsi-2006-30.pdf.

Comment: I should also note that the problem involves a composition of functions which is what I mean by coupled.

Answer (score 0):

My question may have been ill-posed. I believe what would be appropriate is to use a vector or directional regression based off of molecular structure instead of a subspace regression, for example.

Thanks to Paul Sinclair for reinforcing some technicalities.